# How to increment progressbar with current value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a progressbar that calculate current value in percentage and display in progressbar that is working as expected, Every time `$scope.dynamic` value get updates i want to increment progressbar width that has percentage.How can i acheive that task ?I tried with $timeout but that is not doing anything.

ctrl.js

```
   $scope.counter = 0;
    var maxBytes = 5000;
    $scope.max = maxBytes;
    var currentFileBytes = [];
    var currentBytesSum;
    $scope.random = function(value) {
        $scope.dynamic = 'downloaded' + ' ' +  value + ' ' + 'Bytes' + ' ' + '  '+  parseFloat((value/maxBytes) * 100).toFixed(0) + '' + '%' + 'of 1MB';
        console.log('current value-dynamic',$scope.dynamic);
        if (value > $scope.max) {
            // execute download and delete file here if max file size is same
            console.log('bytes are same stop here');
            alert("stop recording");
        }
    };
 $timeout(function () {
     if($scope.dynamic < $scope.max) {
         $scope.counter++;
         $scope.$apply();
     }
 },1000);
```

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-11">
            <uib-progressbar type="success" class="progress-striped" max="max" animate="true" value="dynamic"><span style="font-size: large; color: #0f0f0f">{{dynamic}}</span></uib-progressbar>
        </div>
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly you can use $scope.$watch('dynamic', function(){//logic goes here from timeout function }).....Hope that may give a head start...More info over $watch here https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: This is starting a counter but i want to display percentage that is already displaying in progressbar i just want to increment progressbar  when i receive message based on percentage.

Comment: if you want to increase the width of your progressbar dynamically, you can do it inside `$scope.$watch('dynamic',function(val){...})`. Access the width property of the element you're trying to increase (eg by jquery selector) and assign the correct value[eg `$('#idOfTheBar').css('width', width_you_want_to_assign)`;

Comment: But uib-progressbar has value attribute which will show the current progress..More details over here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: value attribute is not showing current progress as soon as i receive first message value that is `$scope.dynamic` progressbar width extend to 100% even though current value lets assume 10% .

Comment: $scope.dynamic to show progress needs to be numerical...In your code you are concatenating strings as well..

Comment: the code shows value attribute which uses 'dynamic' model inside scope has string value. It needs to be numeric

Comment: that make sense but  how i will display percentage value inside progressbar

Comment: use `{{dynamic/maxValue}}` instead of `{{dynamic}}`. `maxValue` must also be in `$scope`

Comment: I really appreciate your help guys it definitely helped me to resolve this problem. Thank you and SO platform!